# Create Optional param in grok pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

Hi i am trying to create a Grok pattern for the following log event

```
2022-06-22 12:26:40,096 - INFO - test:Upgrade to websocket successful
```

In the above event, `test` is optional some events have it while others do not so I want to handle this in my pattern. What I tried is

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\s-\s%{LOGLEVEL:log-level}\s-\s(%{DATA:class:}\ )?%{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

I need here a little fix,I am getting `test:Upgrade` in class instead of `test`

Comment: if `test` is not available then how your log message will be look ? will it `:Upgrade` or `Upgrade` (without colon)

Comment: If test: is not there it should show null, I already found the solution. Thank you
`%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\s-\s%{LOGLEVEL:level}\s-\s(%{DATA:streamID}\:)?%{GREEDYDATA:loggedString}`